# Golang how to change srcip with udp

Tags: sockets, go, udp

I want change srcip  My code is:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    udpAddr, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp4", "127.0.0.1:1200")
    srcudpAddr, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp4", "127.0.0.2:334")
    checkError(err)
    conn, err := net.DialUDP("udp", srcudpAddr, udpAddr)
    checkError(err)
    str := "###11##22##asdfasdf##adsfadsfasdfasdfasdfasdf11###"
    conn.Write([]byte(str))
}

func checkError(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Fatal error ", err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

I want change the srcudpaddr

```
srcudpAddr, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp4", "127.0.0.2:334")
```

to

```
srcudpAddr, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp4", "211.83.101.20:334")
```

But error

How can do it

If use  scrapy it will be easy

But the golang is no way

Comment: Maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/q/18427655/893693